# why "&#39;" is not getting converted to single quotes while using server.htmldecode()?

Tags: asp.net, html-encode

why ''' is not getting converted to single quotes while using server.htmldecode()?

What is the best way to do the decoding while using '"'"?

Comment: After trying much, I would just use the Replace() function.

Answer (score 2):

This was not supported prior to .NET 4, but you could use this workaround:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1598280/4058759.aspx

The newer version:

http://weblogs.asp.net/vikram/archive/2010/02/18/htmlencode-and-urlencode-now-encode-single-quotation-marks.aspx