# Special characters in sql not displaying correctly

Tags: sql, character-encoding

I have a string that is stored in a tsql database(the expected string should display `"a'string"`) but when I load it into my web browser I see `"a&#39;string"` same for all the special characters. The encoding is also saved as `"a&#39;string"` in the database.

I'm under the belief that my webpage's encoding is different than my db and this is what is causing the issue.

after running:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

I see that the encoding is set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and I have placed

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in the head of my layout page.

I'm very confident that this is not the correct type, and was looking for some guidance as to how to solve this.

I cannot change anything about my SQL server, this is very locked down and read-only.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476638/why-39-is-not-getting-converted-to-single-quotes-while-using-server-htmldec

Comment: Please verify what the string looks like not in a web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem of your SQL, most likely your server side code is converting special char to HTML entities using htmlentities. Not sure what language you are using, PHP for example, you can use html_entity_decode to display it correctly.

```
$str = "a'string";
echo htmlentities($str,ENT_QUOTES);                                //OUTPUT a&#039;string
echo html_entity_decode(htmlentities($str,ENT_QUOTES),ENT_QUOTES); //OUTPUT a'string
```

Comment: This will work, ugh I feel like such a fool!!! And I just used HttpUtility.HtmlDecode.

Comment: As I said, not sure what language you are using, I was giving an example based on PHP. But the idea is universal. For safe you should always use prepared sql statement, like PDO. And if you only want it to display correctly, don't mind how it is stored in the sql, then the above example doesn't do any harm to your current security as it only changes the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is capable of double-byte, that's not the problem.   It appears that you're running into a security measure -- the single-quote being escaped/decoded so that it doesn't go into the database execution as a single quote (which is a string delimiter for SQL).

[why "&#39;" is not getting converted to single quotes while using server.htmldecode()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476638/why-39-is-not-getting-converted-to-single-quotes-while-using-server-htmldec)